# Find which city has the highest number of trips

Tags: python, csv, keyerror

In a csv file, bikeshare data is available for three different cities: NYC, Chicago, Washington. I Need to find which city has the highest number of trips, and also which city has the highest proportion of trips made by subscribers (User_type).

Below is my code:

```
def number_of_trips(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        # set up csv reader object
        reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)        

        # initialize count variables
        ny_trips = 0
        wh_trips = 0
        ch_trips = 0
        n_usertype = 0

        # tally up ride types
        for row in reader:            
            if row['city'] == 'NYC':
                ny_trips += 1
            elif row['city'] == 'Chicago':
                ch_trips += 1
            else:
                wh_trips +=1

            if  wh_trips < ny_trips > ch_trips:
                 city = 'NYC'
            elif ny_trips < wh_trips > ch_trips:
                 city = 'Chicago' 
            else:
                city = 'Washington'
            return city


        # return tallies as a tuple
        return(city, n_customers, n_total)
```

This is throwing an error: `KeyError: 'city'`.

I am very new to python - please guide me on how to achieve above the requirements.

Comment: If you have already attempted something, edit your question and include it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Comment: Does your CSV file have a `city` column header? To increase your chances of getting help, please consult this: [mcve]

Comment: Yeah, file should contain city names.

Comment: data_file = './examples/BayArea-Y3-Summary.csv'
print(number_of_trips(data_file))

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `pandas` library.

```
import pandas as pd

## Reading the CSV
df = pd.read_cvs('file')
## Counting the values of each city entry (assuming 'city' is a column header)
df['city'].value_counts()
```

For the second piece, you can use a pivot table with the `len` as the aggfunc value. The documentation for `pd.pivot_table` is shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).